# IOS Dev Stanford Homework #1 Calculator, can't start

Tags: ios

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h><br>

#import "AppDelegate.h"<br>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])<br>
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    => Thread1: signal SIABRT
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

> Error Message:
>
> 2012-11-03 10:32:08.611 Calculator[9644:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
>
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x342f92a3 0x33acb97f 0x342f8f99 0x392559d1 0x39251723 0x3427f61b 0x36fce245 0x36fcdac3 0x36ec6025 0x36e5046d 0x36e90d79 0x36e8caed 0x36ece1d1 0x36e9183f 0x36e8984b 0x36e31c41 0x36e316d5 0x36e31123 0x34fa95a3 0x34fa91d3 0x342ce173 0x342ce117 0x342ccf99 0x3423febd 0x3423fd49 0x36e88485 0x36e85301 0x77c1 0x38ec4b20)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>       (lldb)

I have no idea how to debug in GDB environment ... Is there any recommendation?

Comment: can you post the link for the homework please

Comment: Also, it's practically useless what you posted. The error is obviously in the `UIApplicationMain` function, since no other function is at the bottom of the call stack as this function never returns. You could have written that the crash occurs "in your program in general" as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually that error means you defined an IBOutlet, then hooked it up in IB, and then deleted that ivar. Check that all the IBOutlets are synthesized and defined in the class.

Comment: Hi Oscar, could you elaborate about the IBOutlet? I started IOS dev 3 days ago ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your IBActions and IBOutlets are connected properly. To debug or add a breakpoint, click the left column beside the code... A blue arrow will appear.. That indicates that you have included a break point...

A good video on how to use the debugger is this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jz1DPud2xyw&feature=BFa&list=UUxlA2SyrGc8vv8wAPknLB7w. Watch it... Very Useful...

Comment: Hi lakesh, I will definitely watch the video. I have solved this issue by looking at the instruction again. It seems I accidentally link 4 buttons from my storyboard into a non-existed function (called test).